# Can someone please translate what she has on her back?

Tags: character-identification

[image]

Hello so I ran into this tattoo and I love how it looks but I would hate to get something I don’t even know means just because it’s cute so I was wondering if someone would be kind enough to translate this for me please. I would also like the words “love,faith,courage” translated please, it would be great if you can help!

Answer (score 1):

It says 主幸活, but this is not a phrase, just three Characters representing three concepts

主 short for "天主" (Lord in heaven) or simply "主" (The Lord), meaning God

幸 short for "幸福" (happiness)

活 short for "生活"(n) (living) or "活著"(adj) (alive)

The tattoo implies "believe in God and you will live a happy life"

> I suspect she confused "生活"(living) with "生命" (life)
>
> "God. Happiness. Life" make more sense than "God. Happiness. Living(n)"